# Spring Data Rest: Default Timestamp Fails and ID returns 0

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-rest

I have a simple MySql table, as follows and I want to post only the 'data' field to Spring Data Rest repo and have both the 'web_order_id' and 'date_added' fields to be automatically added:

```
CREATE TABLE `web_order` (
  `web_order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_added` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`web_order_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

The WebOrder entity is generated via Hibernate Reverse Engineering and outputs the 'web_order_id' and 'date_added' fields as:

```
@Id 
@Column(name="web_order_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
public int getWebOrderId() {
    return this.webOrderId;
}

public void setWebOrderId(int webOrderId) {
    this.webOrderId = webOrderId;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="date_added", nullable=false, length=19)
public Date getDateAdded() {
    return this.dateAdded;
}

public void setDateAdded(Date dateAdded) {
    this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
}
```

Here is the WebOrderRepo:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path="webOrder",collectionResourceRel = "webOrder")
public interface WebOrderRepo extends CrudRepository<WebOrder,Integer> {
}
```

The Problem is when I POST the following JSON body to the WebOrderRepo:

```
{
"data": "{\"value\":\"some long escaped JSON string\"}"
}
```

The date_added column in the DB is set to NULL, and the web_order_id is being incremented properly. I have checked that this is true in the DB, and this is the JSON response from SDR:

```
{
  "webOrderId": 0,
  "dateAdded": null,
  "data": "{\"value\":\"some long escaped JSON string\"}",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/sdr/v1/webOrder/0"
    },
    "webOrder": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/sdr/v1/webOrder/0"
    }
  }
}
```

I can see in the DB that the web_order_id is being incremented for each insert, that none of them have the ID = 0, but SDR returns web_order_id = 0 on *every insert* (rather than the newly created row's ID). I can also see that the date_added is NULL, rather than being auto set.

- Why isn't the timestamp being defaulted to NOW()?
- Why is the return showing the ID = 0, rather than the row ID in the DB?

The MySql 5.5 docs state:

> By default, TIMESTAMP columns are NOT NULL, cannot contain NULL
>   values, and assigning NULL assigns the current timestamp.

I can't figure out why the date isn't being inserted, or how to get the correct ID back. Even if I POST dateAdded = null in the JSON it doesn't auto assign.

Comment: Add your Controller Class for above JSON

Comment: This is Spring Data Rest, the WebOrderRepo (provided) is the Controller (RepositoryRestResource).

Comment: It looks like you have your annotations on the getters, they should be set on the actual variable declarations

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think it's OK this way. This is how hbm2java creates the entity during the reverse engineering process. It works fine in the other entities.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@GeneratedValue` to your `webOrderId` field and `@CreatedDate` to the `dateAdded` field. I have also set the fields to be read-only, like they should.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="web_order_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
private int webOrderId;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="date_added", nullable=false, length=19)
@CreatedDate
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
private Date dateAdded;
```